# Using a map annotation to call segue

Tags: ios, mapkit, segue, mkannotationview, xcode-storyboard

I'm working on a map based application with annotations. I am hoping to connect the accessory button in the annotation callout to a segue to a detail view controller.

I have added a new view controller in storyboard with a push segue from the view controller of the map view with the identify `firePit`

My `ViewController.m` follows as
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "Annotations.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    _mapView.delegate = self;

    //Setting the Visable Region
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.036179, -87.134691);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [_mapView             regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, 2000, 1900)];
    [self.mapView setRegion: adjustedRegion animated:YES];
    //Annotations - Is this the best place?
    CLLocationCoordinate2D firePitCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( 45.037559, -87.130526);
    Annotations *firePit = [[Annotations alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fire Pit" Location:firePitCoord];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:firePit];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Fire Pit";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotations class]]) {

        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [mapView         dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            annotationView.enabled = YES;
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        return annotationView;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"firePit" sender:view]; //thread breakdown 3.1
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(MKAnnotationView *)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"firePit"])
    {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = sender;
        [segue.destinationViewController setAnnotation:annotationView.annotation];
    }
}

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

The app functions in the simulator until I press the accessory button in the annotation callout. It then crashes and alerts me to a thread breakdown in the `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"firePit" sender:view]` method (as commented in the code).

If anyone can offer insight into this problem I would really appreciate it. I can't seem to find assistance from any other resources but if you you have a recommendation I would love a link.

Thanks

Comment: What's the crash error exactly?

Comment: Apologies, that would have been helpful. It's SIGABRT in main auto release pool.

Comment: Using breakpoints, it appears everything is called and it crashes after entering the `if` statement in the `prepareForSegue` method and trying to run the `[segue.destinationViewController setAnnotation:annotationView.annotation]` call. Does anyone see an obvious error with that method?